# I want to exclude certain routes from requiring a JWT Token

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I'm working with Symfony4, API Platform and LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle. It's a requirement to have an access token to access the api, but for certain routes I want them to be public. For example `/api/games` and `/api/games/{id}`.

[image: game api]

api_platform.yaml

```
api_platform:
    mapping:
        paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity']
    swagger:
        api_keys:
            apiKey:
                name: Authorization
                type: header
```

security.yaml

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: argon2i

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        public:
            methods: [GET]
            pattern: ^/api/games
            security: false
        login:
            pattern:  ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            json_login:
                check_path:               /api/login_check
                success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
        api:
            pattern: ^/api/
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            guard:
                authenticators:
                - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
        main:
            anonymous: true
            json_login:
                check_path: /authentication_token
                username_path: email
                password_path: password
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
    - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Comment: Please explain what is not working. The configuration looks good.

Comment: Have you found an answer on how to do that ? Kinda am in the same situation

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove the last line?

```
- { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

And add all secured routes except /api/games.